# How to compare two json responses and see the differences in Postman?

Tags: comparison, postman

I need to create tests in Postman where I compare two responses for two different requests and I want to see what is (if there is anything) the difference between them.
Case is that I can get json response which can contain anything, then I need to check if on different environment the same request gave the same response. 
Right now I do it that way:

In first request I save responsee:

```
pm.globals.set('response', pm.response.json());
```

In second request I compare response with saved one with:

```
pm.test('Should have identical responses as previous', () => {
pm.expect(pm.response.json()).to.deep.equal(pm.globals.get('response'));
});
```

But in this case I just see if there is any difference, so I have to go through a lot of lines each time to find what was wrong.

What I need to get is when I have first response like:

```
[
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    }
]
```

And second like:

```
[
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f2"
    }
]
```

I want to get info in run results like:

```
there is difference in line: value: "#0f2"
```

or

```
in first response there was value: "#0f0" and in second there is value: "#0f2"
```

Is it even possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the solution that I worked with:
In first request I saved response with

```
pm.globals.set('respa', pm.response.json());
```

In second I used function to find differences:

```
function diff(obj1, obj2) {
    const result = {};
    if (Object.is(obj1, obj2)) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if (!obj2 || typeof obj2 !== 'object') {
        return obj2;
    }
    Object.keys(obj1).concat(Object.keys(obj2)).forEach(key => {
        if (obj2[key] !== obj1[key] && !Object.is(obj1[key], obj2[key])) {
            result[key] = obj2[key];
        }
        if (typeof obj2[key] === 'object' && typeof obj1[key] === 'object') {
            const value = diff(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
            if (value !== undefined) {
                result[key] = value;
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

And then also in second response I've added 'if' which create test when there is a difference in responses, and that test is named as difference, and also it's saved in console as json.

```
   pm.globals.set('respb', pm.response.json());
if (!Object.is(pm.globals.get('respb'), pm.globals.get('respa'))) {
    const result = diff(pm.globals.get('respb'), pm.globals.get('res12'));
    console.log(result);
    pm.test('Difference' + JSON.stringify(result), () => {
    pm.expect(0).to.equal(pm.globals.get(1));
});
}
```

Comment: That's nice! It's working. I'm trying to find a place where put diff function and don't repeat it each time. The collection test script doen't seems to communicate with the request test scrypt.

Comment: hey! how can this response work? who res12 from pm.globals.get('res12'))? who is 
 1 from pm.globals.get(1)?